# Calculating of least significant digit of an expression

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, algebraic-number-theory

I want to calculate te least significant digit (1s place) of following:

$ 1+2^{1393} + 3^{1393}+4^{1393} $

> > How we can calculate this? It's very hard for me!

Comment: Here is the brute force answer: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2^{1393}+%2B+3^{1393}%2B4^{1393})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$n^5\equiv n\mod10$$
Using this theorem we have
$$2^{1393}\equiv2\mod10\\
3^{1393}\equiv3\mod10\\
4^{1393}\equiv4\mod10$$
Now we have
$$1+2^{1393}+3^{1393}+4^{1393}\equiv1+2+3+4\equiv10\equiv0\mod10$$
So, the least significant digit is $0$.

Comment: you means 0 okey?

Comment: Yes, $0$ is the least significant digit of this expression.

Answer (score 2):

$$1+2^{1393} + 3^{1393}+4^{1393}$$ is even and $$(1+4^{1393})|5,\,\,\,\,\,(2^{1393} + 3^{1393})|5$$ Hence the last digit is $\color{red}{0}.$

Answer (score 1):

$2^1 = 2, 2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8, 2^4 = 16, 2^5 = 32, 2^6 = 64 ...$
So the least significant digit is a periodic functions depending on degree ($2,4,8,6$)
You should find such periods for $3$ and $4$ and subtract integer number of periods from every degree correspondently. Hope this is enough for you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you would calculate $k^m$ on paper you could start with $k$ and then multiply it by $k$ and so on, $m$ times in total.

Using the decimal system for the last digit $d_0$ this means actually calculating
\begin{align}
d_0^{(1)} &= k \\
d_0^{(i+1)} &= k \cdot d_0^{(i)} \mod 10
\end{align}

For $2^k$ this gives a cycle $2, 4, 8, 6$.

For $3^k$ this gives a cycle $3, 9, 7, 1$.

For $4^k$ this gives $4, 6, 4, 6$

And 1 stays $1, 1, 1, 1$.

Adding those four terms above modulo 10 gives $0, 0, 0, 4$.

As $m = 1393 \mbox{ mod } 4 = 1$ it is the first of the above: $0$.

For $m = 1396$ it would be a $4$.